# Remove element from Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook

I am currently using a social media login plugin for my website that allows users to login via their social media account.

Currently the flow of the plugin works in a way such that after ANY user authenticate themselves through Facebook, they will be brought back to my site with 2 options, link their Facebook account with their site's account, or to register an account.

How can I edit my code such that I am able to remove the "registration account" part without editing the plugin code directly as this might affect future updates of the plugin itself. One way that I know will definitely work is to comment that section away in the plugins itself but I do not wish to touch the plugin code.

After researching, a possible way that I think might work is to apply a filter that removes the element but I am not sure if that is the correct workaround for this situation.

Can anyone shed some light on this matter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to filter executed php code on your Wordpress website.

I got two ways of dealing with this:

1: Disallow people to register an account on your site. The registration link will probably not be displayed anymore.
2: Or comment out the code within the plugin. Remember where you edited the lines. Whenever the plugin gets an update, comment out those lines again. Or contact the owner of the plugin to issue a feature request.